# App download and active user statistics at Huawei App Gallery console

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

How can I know total app download count and active user count from Huawei App Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

You may can use Huawei [Analytics Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-analyticskit/?ha_source=hms1).

Huawei Analytics Kit is a one-stop user behavior analysis platform for products such as mobile apps, web apps, and quick apps. It offers scenario-specific data collection, management, analysis, and usage, helping enterprises achieve effective user acquisition, product optimization, precise operations, and business growth.

Based on the user events and user attributes automatically collected by the Analytics SDK, as well as the reported user behavior data, Analytics Kit can automatically generate data dashboards and analysis reports on user retention, users, user behavior, user lifecycle, app versions, and crashes. In addition, it supports multi-dimensional drill-down analysis and comparison, satisfying data analysis requirements of different roles, such as the marketing personnel, product managers, activity operations personnel, user experience management personnel, and technical developers, as well as driving intelligent business analysis and decision-making.

For more details,pls kindly refer to [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/introduction-0000001050745149?ha_source=hms1).